# Calculating distance to a specific boundary of a multipolygon

Tags: r, polygon, distance, borders

I have a dataset of electric charging station coordinates in LA and multipolygons of school district boundaries. I want to calculate the shortest distance between each station within each district and the  borders of each of the adjoining districts. E.g. if a station is in a district that is surrounded by two other districts, I want to calculate two shortest distances, one to each of the surrounding districts. Is there an easy way to do this in R?

For reference, the data is here:

Charging stations: https://data.lacounty.gov/dataset/EV-Charging-Stations-Map/sawh-si85

School boundaries: https://geohub.lacity.org/datasets/ec0b1dd3637c4535ba4597aaf68716fd/explore

Comment: How do you decide which border you want the distance to? What do you want to do when the polygon is irregular, and there's no clear eastern or western border? Draw a line one of N/S/W/E and take the first intersection? Or take the nearest bounding box? Please edit your question and add some extra information...

Comment: Thanks, I edited the post to clarify what I'm looking for.  I realized the earlier post was confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a column with a unique identifier for both your charging stations and your districts (in my toy dataset these are called `station_id` and `name` respectively).

[image]

```r
library(sf)

## read in the data 
districts <- st_read("E:/data_downloads/misc.gpkg", layer = 'districts')
stations <- st_read("E:/data_downloads/misc.gpkg", layer = 'stations')

## make an empty dataframe to store the results
df <- data.frame(Station=character(),
                 District=character(), 
                 Distance=numeric(), 
                 stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

## make empty list to store all district neighbours
neighbouringDistricts <- list()

## for each district, get the names of its neighbours
for (i in seq_len(nrow(districts))){
  
  currentDistrict <- districts[i,]

  ## get the neighbouring districts by filtering the original sf object
  ## using sparse=FALSE returns only rows that match the st_touches condition
  touching <- districts[which(st_touches(currentDistrict, districts, sparse=FALSE)), ]
  
  ## for each district name, store its neighbours' names as a vector
  neighbouringDistricts[[currentDistrict$name]] <- as.vector(touching$name)
  
}

## loop through charging stations
for (i in seq_len(nrow(stations))){
  
  ## get current station
  currentStation <- stations[i,]
  
  ## get the district that it resides in
  currentDistrict <- districts[which(st_contains(districts, currentStation, sparse=FALSE)), ]
  
  ## get the names of the neighbouring districts from the pre-calculated list
  neighbourNames <- neighbouringDistricts[[currentDistrict$name]]
  
  ## get the neighbouring districts as a spatial object by filtering the districts sf dataframe using the names
  neighbours <- districts[districts$name %in% neighbourNames,]
  
  ## loop through the neighbouring districts
  for (j in seq_len(nrow(neighbours))) {
    
    ## get the current neighbour
    currentNeighbour <- neighbours[j,]
    
    ## get the distance of the current station to the current touching district
    dist <- st_distance(currentStation, currentNeighbour)
    
    ## make a single row dataframe with the Station ID, the name of the current neighbouring district and the distance to that district
    temp.df <- data.frame(currentStation$station_id, currentNeighbour$name, dist)

    ## match the column names with the output df names so `rbind` works as expected
    names(temp.df) <- names(df)
    
    ## append the row to the results dataframe
    df <- rbind(df, temp.df)
  }
  
}

## sort the output by Station ID and then by the distance to neighbouring districts
df <- df[with(df, order(Station, Distance)), ]

View(df)
```

[image]

**Note**
When I was making my toy dataset I was having trouble to get the polygons to truly touch. I am not sure why, as I was using a projected coordinate system on a very small area and I had vertex snapping enabled in QGIS. `st_touches` relies on very precise geometry. You may need to add a distance tolerance, or indeed try a different predicate (e.g. `st_is_within_distance`) if `st_touches` doesn't give you the neighbouring polygons.

Comment: This is great and almost gets me there. From the end data, I won't be able to tell which distance is to which district. That's something I want. For instance, if there are ten districts (which I name as 1-10), I want the final dataset to output distance_to_district_5 and distance_to_district_4 if those are the neighboring districts so I can identify them (instead of neighboring_1 etc.). Does that make sense? Appreciate it if you have any suggestions. I'll see about modifying the loop to figure this out.

Comment: It does make sense indeed and it is something I considered, but it wasn't explicitly mentioned in your question :)

Good luck modifying the code. It's late here so I am signing off, but if you are still stuck tomorrow, I will give it another look.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try. I would also like to add a column that indicates which  district each observation is in. Since the loop is already checking that, hopefully it's straightforward.

Comment: I have edited my answer to give you (hopefully) what you need. It outputs a new dataframe that you can join back to your original charging stations sf dataframe if you need to (using the station identifier as the key)

Comment: It might be more efficient to work out all the "touchings" outside the loop, especially if there's a lot of points in each region, otherwise you're computing all the same "touch" tests multiple times.

Comment: that is a very good point @Spacedman. I have updated my snippet. Reassuringly, it gives the same df output :) Please feel free to optimise further if you see fit.

Comment: I've run into a problem with the code. I'm getting this error: "Error in neighbouringDistricts[[currentDistrict$name]] : attempt to select less than one element in get1index". Any idea how to fix this issue?

Comment: It looks like that particular district doesn't have a neighbour. You could add a print statement to get the ID of the district and then check whether it *should* have a neighbour. If it should then perhaps `st_touches` will have to be swapped for `st_is_within_distance`.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to fix the issue. One question--is the distance in meters or is it degrees? I'm using projection 4326.

Comment: I don't know off the top of my head if sf converts to meters, but you should be able to tell quite easily from your distances. If they are less than 1 then it is likely degrees, otherwise, probably meters. I would recommend transforming to UTM and working in meters from the outset though.

Comment: My dataset was in UTM, note the [m] after the distances, signifying meters. I don't know if that is present when working in 4326